# hardware detail using Java

Tags: java

I want to make a java application software which give the current status/information of the running computer. So, for this, is there any inbuilt/extrnal library present or not?

Can anyone give a simple code which will just. "What is the current status of laptop battery?" or "Is AC adapter is pluged in or not?"

Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

A google search for Java ACPI gives for instance the following result: http://freshmeat.net/projects/jacpi/